# What is the point of cache-level ECC without RAM-level ECC?

Tags: caching, ram, error-correction

This came up in a part selection trade. Some ARM mcu's have cache-level ECC but not RAM-level ECC. It seems like any ECC-protected system is only as strong as its weakest link. Is there a rationale for only cache-level ECC that I am missing?

Answer (score 1):

That is odd! You're right that the DRAM error cross-section is typically larger than the on-chip one, so DRAM is the "weakest link." (Assuming you have a large main memory.)

One possible explanation would be that they use the on-chip ECC for yield improvement, rather than directly for resilience. ECC on caches can be used to tolerate permanent faults in the cache SRAM bits, for instance, allowing the product to be shipped with the cache still enabled.